# How adapt the path to the previous and next article

Tags: php, symfony

I am looking for a solution to access in the current article to the previous(<<) or the next article(>>) at the end of the page of an article.
I thought to get the current paramater of the url with this :

```
{{ dump(app.request.attributes.get('_route_params')) }}
```

and inject in the path with a concatenation to access to the previous or the next. 
I think it's not a bad solution but if I have an article not active. I need to get another one. 
For example : If my current article is the number 10. My previous is the 9 and my next is the 11. If i use my solution, I will have an exception if an article is inactive. In my case the 9 is inactive. I will go to the 8 if the 9 is inactive. 
Thank you to help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a variable defining active/inactive status, you can use a PHP "if" or "if/else" command to only perform your concatenation when the variable defining active status is of a certain value.